# Using xsl:character-map on text nodes only

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to create a generic stylesheet that can convert all Latin characters in Unicode to uppercase ASCII characters.  Using `<xsl:character-map>` works well except for one thing:  namespaces.  The character map converts all of my namespaces to upper case, which I do not want.

Is there a way to utilize a character map to do what I want to all the other nodes while leaving the namespaces untouched?  I see the `disable-output-escaping` attribute might be an option, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: I am confused, http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps says "A character map allows a specific character appearing in a text or attribute node in the final result tree to be substituted by a specified string of characters during serialization." so I wonder why you get namespaces changed when using that feature. Can you post minimal XML input and stylesheet documents demonstrating the problem and also tell us which version of which XSLT 2.0 processor you use exactly?

Comment: @jramos95: @Martin Honnen is rigth. I can't reproduce this.

Comment: The problem may be with my processor.  I am using oracle.xml.parser.v2.oraxsl.  Are either of you using this processor or do you use something else?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know the Oracle processor, as far as I have heard it was developed before XSLT 2.0 was finalized in 2007 and has never been updated to implement the final specification. But I don't know whether that is the reason for the problem you see. You could compare the result to Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, assuming it is Java you are using.

Comment: Looks like this is an Oracle-specific issue.  I'll probably post this on the Oracle Forums then.

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: @jramos95 and @Martin Honnen: Tested with Oracle: it does replace characters in namespace URI with just an identity rule and a character map declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is an Oracle-specific issue.  I'll probably post this on the Oracle Forums then.

Thanks for all the feedback!